# How to create access token for my API using PHP

Tags: php, api

I am new to REST API, I have created API for my website, I used authentication ( username and password ) for API calls.

Now I want Access token to perform API calls, how can I achieve this?

code :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user . ":" . $pass);
```

API end:

```
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] == '$user' && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == '$pass') { 
//code to perform api actions 
}
```

Above code is currently I am using.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    return false;
}elseif(isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) and isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ){
}
```

And This :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But i need to know how to pass and verify access token value to the API.